# Angular-foundation multiple directives asking for transclusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [has-dropdown](https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/#/topbar) directive and I tried to generate recursively navlinks at topbar, but i angular is throwing an error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngInclude, hasDropdown] asking for transclusion on: <li ng-repeat="data in pageList" ng-include="'tree.html'" ng-if="!data.node.length == 0" has-dropdown="">
```

And here's my usage:

```
      <ul class="right">
      <li ng-repeat="data in pageList" ng-include="'tree.html'" has-dropdown>
      </li>
  </ul>

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree.html">
   <a>[[data.name]] [[data.parent]]</a>
    <ul top-bar-dropdown>
        <li ng-repeat="data in data.node" ng-include="'tree.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

I understand i can't use ng-include and has-dropdown in one element, but i need to do something to make it work properly Could you give me a hint to understand my problem to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rxxt3ufG26PAM7GYoNOJ?p=preview
*With simplified data stricture.*

Rearranging the directives in a hierarchical way can help. So that you have in order:

> ng-repeat > ng-include > has-dropdown

```
 <ul class="right">
        <div ng-repeat="data in pageList" ng-include="'tree.html'">
        </div>
   </ul>

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree.html">
<li has-dropdown>
    <a>{{data.name}}</a>
    <ul top-bar-dropdown>
        <li ng-repeat="submenu in data.node" ng-include="'simple.html'"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</script>

 <script type="text/ng-template"  id="simple.html">
//
 </script>
```